# Formalization of one optimization problem or solution of inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, inequalities

I have polynomial:

$p=A_2t^2+A_1t+A_0$

$A_0=(x^2-y^2)+xz$

$A_1=x^2+y^2+z^2+\sin(x)$

$A_2=x^4+y^3+z^2$

$x,y,z$ - parameters, moreover $z$ - the value of which varies in the range $[0,1]$.

Polynomial $p$ has all real solutions if and only if:

$D=A_1^2-4A_0A_2>0$

There are known bounds:

$-1.25<A_0<2,-0.2<A_1<3.8,-1<A_2<3$ and $-1<x<1,-1<y<1$

**Task:** find the intervals for the parameters $x$ and $y$ at which the polynomial $p$ has only real solutions, i.e. the inequality $D>0$ (taking into account the existing bounds) for any $z$ from the specified range.

**Problem:** I tried to solve this problem numerically using the `NMinimize` and `NMaximize`, but to fill the intervals I need to restart the optimization many times, which I want to avoid.

How to solve the problem and get the required intervals for $x$ and $y$ out of the box? I.e. the answer should be something like:

```
x=[?;?] and y=[?;?]
```

My code:

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global` "]

Remove[A, x, y, z]

Subscript[A, 0] = (x^2 - y^2) + x z;

Subscript[A, 1] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + Sin[x];

Subscript[A, 2] = x^4 + y^3 + z^2;

d = Subscript[A, 1]^2 - 4 Subscript[A, 0] Subscript[A, 2];

NMinimize[{x, 
   d > 0, -1.25 < Subscript[A, 0] < 2, -0.2 < Subscript[A, 1] < 
    3.8, -1 < Subscript[A, 2] < 3, -1 < x < 1, -1 < y < 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 5}];

NMaximize[{x, 
   d > 0, -1.25 < Subscript[A, 0] < 2, -0.2 < Subscript[A, 1] < 
    3.8, -1 < Subscript[A, 2] < 3, -1 < x < 1, -1 < y < 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 5}];

NMinimize[{y, 
   d > 0, -1.25 < Subscript[A, 0] < 2, -0.2 < Subscript[A, 1] < 
    3.8, -1 < Subscript[A, 2] < 3, -1 < x < 1, -1 < y < 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 5}];

NMaximize[{y, 
   d > 0, -1.25 < Subscript[A, 0] < 2, -0.2 < Subscript[A, 1] < 
    3.8, -1 < Subscript[A, 2] < 3, -1 < x < 1, -1 < y < 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 5}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a sense of the ranges just by plotting where the discriminant vanishes.

```
aa[0] = (x^2 - y^2) + x*z;
aa[1] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + Sin[z];
aa[2] = x^4 + y^3 + z^2;
poly = Array[aa, 3, 0].t^Range[0, 2];
disc = Discriminant[poly, t];
bounds = {-5/4 <= aa[0] <= 2,
  -1/5 <= aa[1] <= 19/5, -1 <= aa[2] <= 3,
  -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1};

ContourPlot3D[disc == 0, {x, -1, 1},
  {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I simple check at the origin shows that the larger central part is where the discriminant is positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought, what about the problems of more dimension, for which such graphs cannot be built? If only Mathematica could calculate such ranges (where there is a solution that satisfies the conditions). Maybe he can still do it?

Comment: In truth, I don't even know how to express it in mathematical terms. I don't have enough "vocabulary" for that.

Comment: (1) This can become computationally difficult in higher dimensions. The object of interest is the discriminant polynomial, but analyzing that is not always easy. Even for this simple example, an exact set of inequalities describing the space of two real solutions might take a long time to produce (if it is tractable at all).

Comment: (2) I'm guessing this particular example arose from some other field (that is, outside of mathematics). It might help to see what others with domain expertise have done to perhaps simplify the problem.

Comment: (1) You're right, these tasks grew out of robotics, in particular, from the study of spaces of admissible movements. They are closely related to the study of high-order polynomials. Unfortunately, the developed tools are extremely inconvenient for analytical work.

Comment: (2) Therefore, I thought - if the problem is analytically difficult (has a large number of parameters), then the choice of parameters to satisfy the given inequalities should be carried out using the methods of finding the global optimum? The only problem is how to visualize it and work with the number of free parameters> 1 (2 or 3 for example)

Comment: Daniel, to avoid cumbersomeness, I invite you to consider an extended version of the question. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261854/formalization-of-one-optimization-problem-or-solution-of-inequalities-part-2

Comment: For robotics I would expect length parameters to have polynomial terms, and angular parameters to have trig terms. I would not expect to see both types of term from the same variable. This can be an important issue.

Comment: Actually I guess helical (screw) actions can mix polynomial and angular terms together. How algebraically inconvenient...

Comment: The new mathematical apparatus may help. I haven't studied it yet. For this task, see Part 2 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261854/formalization-of-one-optimization-problem-or-solution-of-inequalities-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1 What do you think of the proposal to use the command `FindInstance`?

Comment: `FindInstance` can be useful though it will not give full information (except in the case where it can determine there are no solutions).

Comment: And what if we run the calculation many times, choosing each time a sufficiently large number of points that satisfy the necessary conditions. Thus, we obtain information about the solution space, gradually filling it with possible solutions. The only problem is how to visualize the results?

Comment: For example, in the second part I have 3 free parameters in the range of $[0,1]$ and 3 required parameters. Let's say I choose 3 random combinations of free parameters, substitute them into inequalities and look for such sets of the desired parameters that satisfy these inequalities. How can this be visualized?

Comment: Visualization in 6D might be tricky...

Comment: "Tricky" is putting it mildly ...